# 'Greater than' some value in height()

Tags: jquery, css, height, document

i'm trying to write a jQuery which checks if the document height is greater than some value but it seems it doens't work. So here is what i tried

```
if ($(document).height(>1000px){
    $('#colorpicker').click(function(){
        $('.colorss').css('top', '500px')
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't understand all these unexplained downvotes for all the answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.height()` returns a Number.
Compare it with a number, cause `1000px` is not a Number and `"1000px"` cannot be compared with a number without parsing.

```
var docH = $(document).height(); // returns a Number

if (docH > 1000){
    $('#colorpicker').click(function(){
        $('.colorss').css('top', 500);
    })
}
```

Also , I'm not sure if you want rather to build a statement for your click handler, if yes you might want to try also:

```
$('#colorpicker').click(function(){
    var over1000 = $(document).height() > 1000;
    $('.colorss').css({top: over1000 ? 500 : 150}); // set to 500 otherwise to 150
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code $(document).height() return integer value .

```
if ($(document).height() > 1000){

    code here       

}
```

Comment: please mention reason of for down vote.you need to give reason before give your vote

Answer (score -1):

You have not closed the braces for `.height()` method and `.height()` returns the numeric value. thus you need to check the condition:

```
if($(document).height()>1000){
```